# How do I specify an IPv6 address for a ZeroMQ REQ/REP setup on a local machine?

Tags: zeromq, ipv6

I cannot get a zmq server and client to talk with IPv6, while it easily works with IPv4 with C++.

This is what my ip a shows:

```
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 1c:1b:0d:0c:d7:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.35.208/24 brd 192.168.35.255 scope global dynamic enp0s31f6
   valid_lft 7193sec preferred_lft 7193sec
inet6 fe80::fb7:c6df:9d3a:3d7b/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Server:

```
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t server (context, ZMQ_REP);

server.setsockopt( ZMQ_IPV6, 1);

server.bind("tcp://*:5555%enp0s31f6");
```

Client:

```
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t client (context, ZMQ_REQ);

client.setsockopt( ZMQ_IPV6, 1);

client.connect("tcp://[fe80::fb7:c6df:9d3a:3d7b]:5555%enp0s31f6");
```

The server waits listening, the clients sends the message, the server never gets it. IPv4 works nicely.

What is wrong?

Comment: `("tcp://[fe80::fb7:c6df:9d3a:3d7b]:5555%enp0s31f6")` should you put the scope identifier at the end of the IP address: `("tcp://[fe80::fb7:c6df:9d3a:3d7b%enp0s31f6]:5555")`?

Answer (score 5):

### ZeroMQ API v4.2.2 specification says:

> An interface may be specified by either of the following:
>
> - The wild-card **`*`**, meaning all available interfaces.
> - The primary IPv4 or IPv6 address assigned to the interface, in its numeric representation.
> - The non-portable interface name as defined by the operating system.

The 2<sup>nd</sup> option ought work, if IPv6 gets enabled:

```
client.setsockopt( ZMQ_IPV6, True );                        // ENABLE
client.connect( "tcp://[fe80::fb7:c6df:9d3a:3d7b]:5555" );  // SET
```

Comment: Yes, this is what we found last night. The IPv6 address must be enclosed in square brackets. We didn't find a way to specify an interface name in the address although we will test Ron Mauplin's suggestion.

When we switched to using a non-local address, we needed to turn off our firewall.

Comment: In the `.connect( ... )` method, there is a possibility to attach a source-interface address to be used for outgoing traffic. Ref: `zmq_connect( <socket>, "<tcp>://<targetAddress>:<port#>;<sourceAddress>:<port#>" );`